# Translate DBAccess into swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, translate, dbaccess

Morning All,

Some of you may be familiar with 'DBAccess' an alternative to CoreData written by Adrian Herridge. It is written in ObjC and whilst I have managed to translate the adding of objects into swift I am having trouble doing the same with queries. Here is the ObjC code:

```
DBResultSet* r = [[[[[Person query]
                        where:@"age > 30"]
                        limit:10]
                      orderBy:@"surname,forename"]
                 fetch];
```

You can check out the framework here:

[DBAccess](http://db-access.org/index.php/getting-started/)

Thanks in advance,

Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some investigation it looks like DBAccess does play nicely with Swift but there are some caveats:

Number one, classes seem to need to be defined in a global scope.  And not inline within another class (not sure why yet)

Properties bust be **dynamic var**.

Swift classes must then have an @objc(ClassName) directive added, this allows the original Objective-c code to understand these new objects and inspect them as it previously did.

Here is an example.

```
@objc(Person)
class Person: DBObject  {
    dynamic var forename:NSString!
    dynamic var surname:NSString!
    dynamic var age:NSNumber!
    dynamic var favoriteColour:NSString!
}
```

Hope this helps Jacob.